# What are these metal pieces on the roof?

Tags: hyundai, part-identification, accessories, aerodynamcs, kona

My 2019 Hyundai Kona Electric got 2 of those on the roof:

[image]
[image]

I can't find anything on internet about what it is since I don't know the name and what to look for on Google. So what's the name? What's the purpose of these objects?

Comment: They look like "deer whistle's".

Comment: @RonBeyer well it seems you're right; if you want to post an answer... Feel free!